# Objective C coding error

Tags: iphone

I am getting an error  & Use of undecleared idenifier 'photos'
                         Use of undecleared idenifier 'pic'

here is my code

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                               Use of undecleared idenifier 'photos'


    Photo *pic = [[Photo alloc] init];
    [pic setName:@"Aston Martin"];   Use of undecleared idenifier 'pic'
    [pic setFilename:@"Aston Martin DB6.jpg"]; Use of undecleared idenifier 'pic'
    [pic setNotes:@"Red is my favorite color."]; Use of undecleared idenifier 'pic'

    [photos addObject:pic];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to let the os know what kind of variable photos is like so:

```
NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show photos being declared, and that's what your first error message is complaining about.